# UITableView returning wrong indexPath when moving cells between sections

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm creating a list app where the user can check off items, the checked items move to the bottom (a different section in the `UITableView`) when checked after a short delay. The user can "uncheck" the item by tapping it and it moves back to the original section.

My problem is that when the cells are moving between sections like this it seems the `UITableView` get "confused" about where which cells are.

When I `NSLog` the `IndexPath.row` of the cell I'm interacting with it returns a different row than I'm touching. I use `[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:from_indexPath toIndexPath:to_indexPath];` to move the cells between sections. Here's some of my code:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

switch (indexPath.section) {
    case SECTION_ACTIVE:{
        ItemData *dataForCell = [activeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       NSLog(@"%@ \t %d",dataForCell.title, indexPath.row);
        if (dataForCell.isHeader) {
           NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
            return 70;
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}

return 55;
}
```

Is there any way to work around this? Or to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can tag your table cells and can re-check it when you move your cell from one section to another.